# DSE: Synonym Search (Thesaurus)

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am currently trying to get synonym search to work on multiple nodes via Datastax Studio if possible. The installation was done through OpsCenter with 3 nodes using DSE Search + Graph. I have seen various posts regarding this and the approaches consists of directly changing schema.xml. However, as I am using multiple nodes I am unsure if that is the way to approach this.

I have also tried to look information from datastax docs but couldn't find what i needed, hence, any advise or directions on this would be greatly appreciated. In an Ideal world it would be great if I am able to do synonym search through the graph(gremlin) interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Graph the only option is to create necessary indexes, then get the existing `schema.xml` via `dsetool get_core_schema`, do modifications, and load it again with `dsetool reload_core` - the reloading of core should be done in every data center, but not on every machine of the data center...

Don't forget, that before reloading the core with modified schema, you need to upload synonym files with `dsetool write_resource`.

See the [DSE Search documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/customIndexResources.html) for full list of the options for `dsetool` command.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply @Alex Ott, I have managed to complete synonym searches and would like to ask if we can do "OR" queries using DSE graph search? I can't seem to find an example for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not expert in the DSE Graph, I would suggest to ask on DataStax Academy Slack...